# Unity Errors Always happening no matter what

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I have just started to use unity. (I mean i just started today) I've have been following a tutorial and i am doing everything right. But no matter what i receive 3 errors. I decided to start a new project before i do anything i built it and receive the same errors here are the errors.

error 1

```
be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String 
assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, 
System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at 
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:154)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, 
System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at 
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:194)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

error 2

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

error 3

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer 
(BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in 
C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182 
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean 
askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in 
C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Comment: What version of unity are you using?

Comment: Do you get those error just by opppening the program or when trying to Play without any Script or are you using a custor Script?

Comment: I mean it cant even be compiled. I can play test it in unity but i can't compile it. I am using 2018.1.4f1 Personal

Comment: Are these errors in the Unity Console, or errors with your IDE?  If you want to build with unity you build using file -> build settings

Comment: The errors are in the console and i have been using build setting to build or build and run

Comment: Some lines of the first error are missing, could you add them to your question?

Comment: I realized all i need to do is get an older version of unity.